# How can i use a component inside a Cell?

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I'm looking for a way to use component inside a cell, is there any way ?

I tried :

```
$this->loadComponent('SessionsActivity');
```

My Cell :

```
namespace App\View\Cell;

use Cake\Core\Configure;
use Cake\View\Cell;

class UserCell extends Cell
```

My query :

```
$user = $this->Users
    ->find()
    ->where([
        'Users.id' => $this->request->id
    ])
    ->contain([
        'Towns' => function ($q) {
            return $q->find('short');
        },
        'Countries' => function ($q) {
            return $q->find('short');
        }
    ])
    ->map(function ($user) {
        $user->online = $this->SessionsActivity->getOnlineStatus($user);
        return $user;
    })
    ->first();
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the same example at the [CakePHP cells documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/cells.html#implementing-the-cell), suppose you want to show the inbox for the connected user. You'd want to access the Auth component to take the connected user id.

AFAIK, Cells act like view-controller, a view part `display.ctp` file, and a controller part where you access the model to generate data for the view.

I'm using CakePHP 3.0 and `$this->_registry` doesn't work.

Comment: Answering myself. If you want to read id of the connected user or any other session data from a Cell, you can use the `request` object that contains the entire session: `$this->request->session()->read('Auth.User.id')`

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
$this->SessionsActivity = $this->_registry->load('SessionsActivity');
```

it is another question if you should use a component here

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same solution but i use cakephp 4.
You question and answere did help finding the solution.

In **cakephp 3** it should work like you wrote in you comment, but i did not test it.

```
$user_id = $this->request->session()->read('Auth.User.id');
```

In **cakephp 4** you can use

```
$identity = $this->request->getSession()->read('Auth')
```

or

```
$identity = $this->request->getAttribute('identity');
```

to get the Users Session data inside a cell.

Then you can work with the users data

```
echo $identity->username;
echo $identity->email;

$user = $this->Users
    ->find()
    ->where([
        'Users.id' => $identity->id
    ])
    ->contain([
        'Towns' => function ($q) {
            return $q->find('short');
        },
        'Countries' => function ($q) {
            return $q->find('short');
        }
    ])
    ->map(function ($user) {
        $user->online = $this->SessionsActivity->getOnlineStatus($user);
        return $user;
    })
    ->first();
```